# UWP - Display placeholder on gridview image binding while still loading

Tags: c#, json, image, gridview, uwp

I have an image binding on gridview with XAML below:

```
<Border x:Name="coverBox" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,10,0,0" Width="230" Height="170" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}">
                                <Image x:Name="cover" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Width="230" Height="170"/>
</Border>
```

Code:

```
string urlPath1 = "http://..../API/sekolah";
                            var httpClient1 = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                            var values1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                            {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", "...."),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("limit", limit++.ToString()),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("hal", noHal++.ToString())
                            };

                            var response1 = await httpClient1.PostAsync(urlPath1, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values1));
                            response1.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                            if (!response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                busyIndicator.IsActive = false;
                                RequestException();
                            }
                            string jsonText1 = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            JsonObject jsonObject1 = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText1);
                            JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject1["data"].GetArray();

                            foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                            {
                                JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();
                                string thumbnail = groupObject2.ContainsKey("thumbnail") && groupObject2["thumbnail"] != null ? groupObject2["thumbnail"].GetString() : string.Empty;

                                ListingClass file1 = new ListingClass();
                                file1.Thumbnail = thumbnail;

                                listingDatasourceDetail.Add(file1);
                            }
                            listingGridView.ItemsSource = listingDatasourceDetail;
```

I want while still loading to take the image data from JSON, then show the paceholder `images/SEKOLAH-place-holder-600.png` first

How to add placeholder while still loading?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `cover` Image within a Grid, then create another Image to display the placeholder png and place it behind `cover`.

Comment: I want to not use 2 images because in the picture there are some of the background is transaparan. So the placeholder remains visible

Comment: You can subscribe to ImageOpened event and set the Visibility of the placeholder image to Collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `Loading` event to Image :

```
    private void myimage_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
        {
            Image myimage = (Image)sender;
            myimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/SEKOLAH-place-holder-600.png"));
        }
```

Comment: The code can not be used because the image is in the gridview so it is not detected

Comment: I've tried it. But even though loading is complete, the displayed image is just a placehoder (image does not appear).

Comment: Khaled: can you help me?